# ng-change not getting called angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have below HTML code, and I am adding following code at run time.

```
var html = "<select class='my-class' id='test' ng-change='onChange()'> <option value='0'>Zero</option> ... </select>";
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = html;
```

In my controller :

```
$scope.onChange = function()
{
    console.log("Changed");
}
```

But my onChange method is not getting called.

Comment: You should use $compile method for this.Check the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). `var html = $compile("<select class='my-class' id='test' ng-change='onChange()'> <option value='0'>Zero</option> ... </select>")(scope);`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp

Comment: @RaghvendraKumar the problem is that he put the HTML after angularjs compile the page.

Comment: no need to add `<select>` tag at run time, maybe you can use `ng-if` if you do not want `<select>` tag to be created in the DOM, other options `ng-show`, `ng-hide`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that, as described in AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> The **ngChange** expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the **model**. Note, this directive requires **ngModel** to be present.

Another problem is that you need to use `$compile`. Example:

```
var element = angular.element("<select class='my-class' ng-model='myModel' id='test' ng-change='onChange()'> <option value='0'>Zero</option> ... </select>");
elementCompiled = $compile(element)(scope);
parentElement.append(elementCompiled);
```

**Edit:**

An example:

```
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope, $compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
    var parentElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#parent'));
    var element = angular.element("<select class='my-class' ng-model='myModel' id='test' ng-change='onChange()'> <option value='0'>Zero</option> ... </select>");
    parentElement.append($compile(element)($scope));
}]);

<div id="parent" ng-controller="Ctrl"></div>
```

Comment: I got error $compile(html)(scope); -- Error: Can't find variable: scope. Working example will help more.

Comment: That code block should be used for example within a controller or directive where you have direct access to scope.

Comment: @user3632710 have you forgotten to add $ with scope ?

Comment: I didn't know whether or not he's using $scope or scope so I used scope. Eitherway I improved my answer with an example.